# python: turn json string to dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I received data through socket where the data is a dictionary, but when it sendes through the socket, it has to be Json string, so when I receive it, I need to turn it back to dictionary. How can I turn Json string to dictionary ?
I tried to do loads like `newdata = json.loads(data)`, but it doesn't turn it back to dictionary

```
data = connection.recv(4096)
    if data:
        print "Received", repr(data)

        data = data.rstrip()
        connection.send("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % ("-" * 80, data.center(80), "-" * 80))
        print "Response sent!"
        newdata = json.loads(data)
        for k, v in newdata.iteritems():
            AllData[v] = k
```

NewData looks like this : `{u'1009.2': [1, 1], u'1018.2': [0, 0]}`
but for loop treats newdata as a string.

Comment: instead of `AllData[v] = k` trying printing values `k` and `v` to verify if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your string has invalid JSON data. There must be no `u` in front of string literals, and they must be included in double quotation marks.

The problem probably arises because the sender uses `str(d)` to serialize the dictionary. If you can control the sender, let it use `json.dumps(d)` for serialization:

```
d = {'1018.2': [0, 0], '1009.2': [1, 1]}
data = str(d)
# "{'1018.2': [0, 0], '1009.2': [1, 1]}" - bad!
data = json.dumps(d)
# '{"1018.2": [0, 0], "1009.2": [1, 1]}' - good!
```

If you cannot control the sender, you can deserialize the data that you get with `ast.literal_eval(data)`:

```
d = ast.literal_eval(data)
# {'1018.2': [0, 0], '1009.2': [1, 1]}
```